# Android studio multidexenable true taking 3 mins to build the entire project

Tags: android, android-studio

there were my compile time dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.3@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.4.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0"
compile "com.quantumgraph.sdk:QG:1.1.11"
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not an unusually long time with a multidex project. One way you could speed it up is by only including the libraries from google play services you need as "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0" is a huge library. This page shows how to do this:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

See under "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable".

Infact, depending on how large the other libraries are, you may find by only using the google play services apis you need that you no longer need to enable multidex.

Comment: yes! yes! break up those play services